# Symfony 3 FOSRestController Format_listener can't resolve path

Tags: php, json, symfony, fosrestbundle

I extend my Controller with the FOSRestController to response json data.

This is my domain:

> http://example.com/api/middleware/export/itscope/8d4b0468-fa91-4861-ae4b-bde72b983bad

And this is in my controller:

```
<?php

namespace My\MiddlewareBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;


class ExportController extends FOSRestController
{

    public function indexAction($exportId)
    {
        $result = exportSomeThingSpecial($exportId);
        return $this->handleView($this->view(['test' => 'bla'], ($result) ? 201 : 500));
    }
}
```

And my config contains:

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
        include_format: false
    allowed_methods_listener: true
    param_fetcher_listener: force #reading parameters from the request
    body_listener: true #decoding the request content in the request
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
        formats:
            json: true
            xml: false
            html: false
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    format_listener: #determining the correct response format
        enabled: true
        rules:
            - { path: '^api/middleware', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
            - { path: '^/', stop: true }
```

But it throws this error:

```
{

    "error": {
        "status": 500,
        "message": "Unable to find template \"\" (looked into: /var/www/app/Resources/views, /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form)."
    }

}
```

When I remove the path statement of the format_listener it works.
So that the format_listener contains this:

```
format_listener: #determining the correct response format
        enabled: true
        rules:
            - { priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
            - { path: '^/', stop: true }
```

But I don't want that json response in my whole app.
So I need this for a specific part of my application in this case:

> /api/middleware/export/{exportId}

How do I do this in the right way?